# Different sans serif font for captions

Tags: fonts, captions, sans-serif

In my document, I want to use palatino as the main text font, and Arev (or Myriad Pro) for captions. I found some relevant question on stackexchange, but none of them works for me :(

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{palatino, mathpazo}
\usepackage{arev}
\usepackage[font=sf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{lll}
1 & 1 & 1  \\
2 & 2 & 2  
\end{tabular}
\caption{My table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I know this is a silly approach, but it's here just to give an idea.

Ideally, I would like to use MyriadPro, but I can't figure out how to use it on Overleaf. Do you think it's possible? In particular, with pdfLaTeX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trick is to load `mathpazo` after rather than before `arev`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{arev,mathpazo} % no need to load 'palatino' package
\usepackage[font=sf]{caption}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
1 & 1 & 1  \\
2 & 2 & 2  
\end{tabular}
\caption{My table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Incidentally, since the x-height of `arev`'s glyphs is so much larger than that of `mathpazo`'s glyphs, you may want to set `\usepackage[font={sf,small}]{caption}` or even `1\usepackage[font={sf,footnotesize}]{caption}` in order to prevent the captions from looking visually overpowering.

Comment: thanks so much! I hope one day I'll understand the logic behind LaTex